# How to solve $\frac{dx(t)}{dx}=-a\frac{dV(x)}{dx}$ for a known potential $V$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$\frac{dx}{dt}=-a\frac{dV}{dx}$ where $a$ is a positive constant and $V(x)=k[b+erf(x/c)]$. Is there any analytical way of solving this?

Using the chain rule, I can get $\frac{dV}{dt}=-a(\frac{dV}{dx})^{2}$, but I don't know if I simplify anything this way...

UPDATE: I wrote incorrectly the second term before

Comment: It comes from newton but I consider other hypothesis:
$\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}=-\frac{dV}{dx}-\gamma \frac{dx}{dt}$ and then I assume damping is strong enough $\Rightarrow \gamma \frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{dV}{dx}$

Comment: Yes, I wrote the equation incorrectly. Just corrected it, sorry!

Comment: In your new formulation. Let $f(x) = \frac{dV}{dx}$ (for ease of notation) then the equation is seen to be separable: $\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)} \frac{dx}{f(x)} = -a\int_0^t dt = - at$. Don't know if the integral can be solved analytically though.

Comment: That's exactly where I'm getting stuck. I get $\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}e^{x^{2}/c^{2}}dx=t*constant$ but the integral of the left...

Comment: Well that integral does not have a simple antiderivative. It can formally be written in terms of the [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) however this does not help that much as you would need to invert it to get an explicit solution $x(t)$. I guess you could examine the solution approximately using known asymptotics of the error function.